# Convert webpage in other language?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-translate

I have created one django appEngine website in english language i want to convert that site in other language like hindi gujrati and much more language and give just one button on top of that converet in gujrati, hindi and any other language and hole site will be convert in to that perticular language.
Like in google crome that provide that facility to convert site in any language.

Comment: Duplicated! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280881/django-site-with-2-languages

Comment: @Othman I want to try use google trancelate api not use the codding.through change i want trancfer hole site in other language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways -

1. Use Django's own [i18n and l10n](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) feature. Provide your own translations and urls to use them.
2. Use [Google's translation toolbar](http://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=en), that shows an option like you mentioned happens in Google chrome. It'll show a toolbar with translate button with a language option and using it will translate whatever text you have on the page.