# URL rendered as home_page after internationalization

Tags: django, internationalization, django-views, django-urls, django-i18n

I have a Django Website that I am trying to internationalize. Until now it looked like this:

Homepage:

- `www.myhomepage.com`

Another page:

- `www.myhomepage.com/content/cities`

---

Now I am trying to make it like this:

Homepage:

- `www.myhomepage.com/en`
- `www.myhomepage.com/de`

Another page:

- `www.myhomepage.com/en/content/cities`
- `www.myhomepage.com/de/content/cities`

---

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280881/django-site-with-2-languages) and [this](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/internationalization-localization-languages-time-zones), I managed to make the homepage work, so with `www.myhomepage.com/en` I see the homepage in English and with `www.myhomepage.com/de` I see it in German.

The problem comes when I want to go to any other page, like `www.myhomepage.com/en/content/cities`. Then, the page rendered is still the homepage. Before changing any settings to internationalize it `www.myhomepage.com/content/cities` was showing up properly.

My guess is that the problem is with the view rendering or the url, but I do not manage to make it work.
Note that the view for `www.myhomepage.com` belongs to one app and the view for `content/cities` belongs to a different app.

---

This is the code I have:

`settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('German')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_I18N = True
```

### Main app:

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^content/', include('content.urls', namespace='content')),
)
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_view(request):

    ...

    context = {
                ...
    }

    #print('request home', request)

    return render(request, 'home_template.html', context)
```

By activating the print statement and loading `www.myhomepage.com/en/content/cities`, the following is printed in the console: `request home: <WSGIRequest: GET '/en/content/cities/'>`, even though this view belongs to the home_page.

### Content app:

`urls.py`

```
from .views import countries_and_cities

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^cities/$', countries_and_cities),
    ...
]
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def countries_and_cities(request):

    ...

    context = {
                ...
    }

    return render(request, 'cities_template.html', context)
```

I have also tried what it is suggested in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns), without success.

`urls.py` from main app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

from content import views as content_views
content_patterns = ([
    url(r'^cities/$', content_views.countries_and_cities, name='cities'),
], 'content')

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^content/', include(content_patterns, namespace='content')),
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

There was another url defined as:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    ...
    url(r'', include('main.urls')),
    ...
    )
```

This was causing the problem, even if before going for internationalization it was working properly.

I just changed it to:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    ...
    url(r'^$', include('main.urls')),
    ...
    )
```

And it is working properly.