# Django 2.1 Site With Two (or More) Languages

Tags: python, django, django-models, internationalization

I am currently researching a solution or approach to the following problem. We need a site that will operate in at least two different languages. The site is Django 2.1-based and uses DjangoCMS. It will have a multi-language blog-like capability in which articles will be published in different languages. Videos will also be posted there. We would like to have an ability to post separate content to different (language) sides of the site. The user will be able to select their language preference in the navigation bar and that version of the site will be served to him from there on.

It appears that we would like to have to have two different sets of paths along the lines of

`www.example.com/lang1/*`

`www.example.com/lang2/*`

That is, each (or most) pages will be present on more than one language side and the only difference between the paths will be the language prefix. That said, the slugs would need to be in the native language of the pertinent material, if that matters at this point. This is the vision, but it is certainly negotiable.

While doing the research, I have found questions like this which have  been helpful:

[Django site with 2 languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280881/django-site-with-2-languages)

However, it appears that I am still somewhat confused about what needs to happen. My confusion can be summarized (in no particular order) by

1. How current are the discussions in the question above? Has much changed between then and the time of Django 2.1?
2. What is the overall approach one should be taking when trying to solve a problem like this?
3. What is the difference between Translation and Internationalization when it comes to Django terminology?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? There is a [whole section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/) that explains everything you asked.